# Avoiding the deferred anti-pattern

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some code that looks like this:

```
function foo() {

    var deferred;

    deferred = q.defer();

    doSomethingAsync()
        .then(function(result) {
            var resultTransformed = doSomethingSynchronousToTheResult(result);
            deferred.resolve(resultTransformed);
        });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```

Maybe:

```
function foo() {            
    return doSomethingAsync()
        .then(function(result) {
            return doSomethingSynchronousToTheResult(result);
        });       
};
```

Would the above ensure that the transformed result is used further down the promise chain?

How can I refactor this to avoid the deferred anti-pattern?

Comment: I would think this question is already handled in the canonical post, isn't it? `return doSomethingAsync().then(doSomethingSynchronousToTheResult)` is just the solution  suggested there.

Answer (score 6):

Deferred anti-pattern happens when new redundant deferred object is created to be resolved from inside an promise chain.

In your case you already have a Promise object, so you just need to return `doSomethingAsync()` result:

```
function foo() {
    return doSomethingAsync().then(function (result) {
        return doSomethingToTheResult(result);
    });
};
```

> Would the above ensure that the transformed result is used further down the promise chain?

Yes, exactly, this is one of the coolest things about promises.

Comment: But if the `doSomethingToTheResult` is asynchronous and not promise based, I *do* need to create a new deferred. Is that correct?

Comment: If `doSomethingToTheResult` is async then yes, inside you would need to create deferred and return promise.

Comment: @BenAston Either that, or you can create a promise using the promise constructor.