# How to get variables properly with Angularjs promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I couldn't figure out this problem. My question is why I cannot resolve responses. And I cannot use the responses in my controller. But I get 6  responses as empty. Please open console and push "Get Result" button under the google map. You will see undefined array.

here is  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kPeH2uxLRQStoyLMMv3A?p=preview)

```
 getGoogleDirection.getData(response,$scope.mymap).then(function(res){
                console.log(res); // **it returns undefined elements**
            });
```

And here are services.

```
    App.factory('setData',function($q){
    return {
        getData:function(array){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var newArray = [];
            angular.forEach(array,function(firstBlocks,key){
                var dummy = firstBlocks.chunk(9);
                angular.forEach(dummy,function(last,key2){
                    if(key2!=0){
                        dummy[key2].unshift(dummy[key2-1][dummy[key2-1].length-1]);
                    }
                });
                newArray.push(dummy);
            });
            deferred.resolve(newArray);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}); 
App.factory('getGoogleDirection',function($q){
    return {
        getData:function(array,mymap){
            var distances = [];
            var promises = []
            angular.forEach(array,function(object,key){
                angular.forEach(object,function(array2,key2){
                    promises.push(getDirection(array2));
                });
            });
            function getDirection(array){
                var wayPoints = [];
                var start = array[0];
                var finish = array[array.length-1];
                array.pop();
                array.shift();
                angular.forEach(array,function(item,key){
                    wayPoints.push({
                        location:new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.lat),parseFloat(item.lng)),
                        stopover:true
                    });
                });
                calcRoute(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(start.lat),parseFloat(start.lng)), wayPoints, new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(finish.lat),parseFloat(finish.lng)));
            }
            function calcRoute(start,waypoints,end) {
                var directionsDisplay;
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                directionsDisplay.setMap(mymap);
                    var request = {
                        origin:start,
                        destination:end,
                        waypoints:waypoints,
                        optimizeWaypoints: false,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                        avoidHighways:false,
                        avoidTolls:false
                    };
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                return directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }else{
                        deferred.reject(response);
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                });
            }
            return $q.all(promises).then(function(res){
                return res;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764182/avoiding-the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will read it. I have updated the question. Could you check it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the promise is resolved it provides the resolved data in its callback function. In your code you are not using that.

Change this piece of code

```
              var dist = [];
              angular.forEach(data, function (d) {
                if (d) dist.push(d);
              });
              console.log(dist);
              return dist;
```

Take a look here
http://plnkr.co/edit/dmlhpWKUxL7CLb1ej8FV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is not that I want. You just get an array of undefined elements.. I need to get the distances array when loop done.

Comment: Take  a look at my edited answer. Now it is rendering the map as well.

Comment: sorry but data is empty. I need to get distances. The problem is not rendering. it already renders. open console and see the console. You will see an empty array... I need to get distances.

Comment: `dist`  array contains the distances.

Comment: Sorry. nope. dist is an empty array

Comment: Oh sorry there was a typo in the code. Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/dmlhpWKUxL7CLb1ej8FV?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. But please open console. And you will see dist is an empty array

Comment: ok. You don't understand my problem. when open console. you will see an empty array.

Comment: I think now I have solved your code. Take a look a this latest plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/dmlhpWKUxL7CLb1ej8FV?p=preview

Comment: Yes. I think I understand the problem. I defined $q.defer() only one time. Actually I had to define the $q.defere for each loop. I got it. Thank you. You are amazing. You helped me lot.

Answer (score 2):

`$q.all(promises)` finishes when all promises are finished, however the `promises` array does not contain promises at all. What is added to the promises array is the return value of `directionsService.route`, which is not a promise. When you give $q a non promise to resolve it acts like a promise that is resolved to that same value. For example:

```
      $q.when(1).then(function(x) {
        alert(x);
      });
```

Will alert '1', even though 1 is not a promise.

So what you need to do is return a promise that resolves when in the route callback `status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK`. When your promises resolve properly you can use distances.

However, it is much better to resolve your promises with a distance, so the end result would be something like this:

```
var result = $q.deferred();
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var distances = [];
        angular.forEach(response.routes[0].legs,function(leg){
              distances.push(leg.distance.value);
          });
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); // 
        result.resolve(distances);
    }else{
        result.reject('Google dan veri alımında hata yaşandı');
    }
});
return result.promise;
```

You can then use it like this: `$q.all(promises).then(function(allDistances) { ... }`, where allDistances is a 2d array of distances, whereas the first index corresponds to the route and the second index to the leg.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you edit the plunker ?

Comment: Actually I call directionservice more than one time in this example. So you just return only one element for the loop which is promises.push(getDirection(array2));

Comment: I have updated the question and plunker :) I still cannot get responses.

Comment: I have given you the correct answer to what your problem was (your promises were not promises), now you should be able to solve it by yourself. Stackoverflow is not a place where other people code for you, but a place you can ask questions. Perhaps ShankarSangoli is willing. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but this is not solution. I have updated question.

Comment: Yes. I think I understand the problem. I defined $q.defer() only one time for the loop. in fact I had to define the $q.defere for each loop. I got it. Thank you. You are amazing. You helped me lot.